# Optimal index for selecting all records within the past n period?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

#### Question

Is there an optimal indexing strategy (or other optimization) for reading from a single table in reverse chronological order in Postgres?

#### Background

I'm working on a system where I'll need to query a single table for all records within the last n hours or days. The table will likely never have more than 250,000 records in total, perhaps half of which will actually be streamed out at a time. The ratio of writes to reads is ~10,000:1. Given reads are relatively low, I suspect it may not make sense to apply any sort of read optimization but wanted to ask.

Comment: A simple index on the timestamp will allow the engine to read rows sorted by it.

Comment: With that ratio of writes to reads, and with the reads being large anyway, you are probably better off with no index.

Comment: It's hard to comment without more details, but also look into partitioning.